# simple question regarding moving files and folders

Tags: command-line, directory, mv

I am a noob, gains are slow. working on moving things around, playing.

Command: `mv man-pages(man-pages folder) /bob`. instead of moving the `man-pages` folder(directory?) to directory bob, it took all 10 files inside the man-pages folder and dumped them into bob. command: `ls` in bob instead of a man pages folder i have the 10 folders which was inside it.  in search i dont see a different command to move folders, mv is for file and folder?

what should i have done to move this folder?

how to i take all ten of these files(which are all actually sub-folders) and put them back under a single folder/directory? one thing i looked at has me entering on the command line each of these files one at a time?

EDIT: after some more playing, ive discovered ive created a "bob" directory under root? now i'm confused.

```
bob@adminbaby:/home$ cd bob
bob@adminbaby:~$ pwd
/home/bob
bob@adminbaby:~$ ls
Desktop    Downloads  Pictures  skip.txtsss  Templates
Documents  Music      Public    snap         Videos
bob@adminbaby:~$ cd bob
bash: cd: bob: No such file or directory
bob@adminbaby:~$ cd /bob
bob@adminbaby:/bob$ pwd
/bob
bob@adminbaby:/bob$ ls
Changes       etc          lsm       man3       man4  man8     share
Changes.old   GNUmakefile  man1      man3const  man5  README
CONTRIBUTING  INSTALL      man2      man3head   man6  RELEASE
CPPLINT.cfg   LICENSES     man2type  man3type   man7  scripts
bob@adminbaby:/bob$ cd .
bob@adminbaby:/bob$ ls
Changes       etc          lsm       man3       man4  man8     share
Changes.old   GNUmakefile  man1      man3const  man5  README
CONTRIBUTING  INSTALL      man2      man3head   man6  RELEASE
CPPLINT.cfg   LICENSES     man2type  man3type   man7  scripts
bob@adminbaby:/bob$ cd ..
bob@adminbaby:/$ pwd
/
bob@adminbaby:/$ ls
bin   dev   lib    libx32      mnt   root  snap      sys  var
bob   etc   lib32  lost+found  opt   run   srv       tmp
boot  home  lib64  media       proc  sbin  swap.img  usr
bob@adminbaby:/$ pwd
/
```

ok....so / is "root" and i created a directory there "bob". But what i was trying to do was put it @ bob that has Downloads, Pictures, etc. i thought ~ and / meant the same thing?

Comment: What was the actual command you used for the `mv man-pages(man-pages folder) /bob`?

Answer (score 0):

`/` is the root directory. So, if you `mv` a directory to `/`, it is moved to the root directory. Nothing strange there. If you want to `mv` it to `/home/bob`. you should `mv` it there.

If `/home/bob` is your home directory, you can also `mv man-pages ~`. `~` is a sort of abbreviation for your home directory.

To get the directory under your home directory, simply `mv /bob ~/man-pages` (assuming that there is no directory `man-pages` under your homedir yet`.

Now there is something strange, at least non-standard, in your situation. You were able to create a directory directly under `/` as a normal user. You should not have been able to do that.

Comment: I posted the wrong code it appears. I did use mv as you stated, i just made a rookie error where i was sending it. but what i didnt understand is why instead of the folder "man-pages" being moved, it took all the folders inside of it out of the containing folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Clarification on root and user directories**

In a computer, there is one root user and possibly multiple other users.

`/` refers to the root user directory.

Now, the root user has access to data for all users.

`/home/{user}` is the place where the data for all users other than the root user are present.
As an example, `/home/bob` is where your data is present, where your Downloads, Documents and other folders sit.

So,
`/` is root dir.

`/home/bob` is a dir inside your root dir.

`~` is "your"(bob's) home dir, which means it is the same as `/home/bob`

And if you want to know which user you are logged in with currently, simply do -

```
$ whoami
bob
```

**mv command syntax**

```
$ mv <what to move> <where to move>
```

*case 1: You want to move a file or a directory*

```
$ mv <file/dir name> <where to move>
```

*case 2: You want to move everything that is present inside dir1 to dir2*

```
$ mv dir1/* dir2
```

As can be understood, in case 2, if you move everything from inside `dir1` to `dir2`, `dir1` will become empty.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was helpful and clarified things for me. sorry I cant' upvote your answer.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

One method would be `cp -r`; the `-r` flag is required to move the directory contents as well.

Pulling up the man page for `mv` will likely have the same flag.